# Javascript intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I created the new project with the help of yeoman generator:

```
yo express
```

After opening the project in vscode I created the default jsconfig.json file with the following content:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "jspm_packages",
    "tmp",
    "temp"
]
```

}

Intellisense works fine for my modules. For example, this is my module:

```
function Lesson(data) {
  this.name = data.name;
}

Lesson.prototype.printMe = function () {
  console.log(this.name);
}

module.exports = Lesson;
```

But it does not work for node.js modules, for example, for express:

[image]
So, the question is, why intellisense doesn't work for node.js modules?

Comment: Looks like you currently need a [typings file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs#_intellisense-and-typings) to tell it about frameworks and external code.

Comment: Ok, but why does it work well for my modules without any typings file?

Comment: Because it doesn't know how to resolve the path to node modules. For example, try doing `require('./node_modules/express')` without any kind of typing file. The intellisense will (mostly) work because it knows how to resolve that path. Automatic node_modules lookup would definitely be a nice feature though.

Comment: @MikeC Ok, I tried to do this and now the situation is a little bit better but still not good. I thought that the default moduleResolution mode is "node" but then I realized that it was for tsconfig.json.
So, as I see by default vscode will provide me IntelliSense for my modules. To be able to get intellisense for external modules I have to use definitions, right?

Comment: I believe so. Honestly, everything I told you came from some quick Google work and experimentation.

Comment: I knew this because I've been using typescript and definitions some time. But I asked because wanted to know the "true way" for vscode to provide intellisense. And it seems the definitions is that way. Thank you.

Comment: The question was answered in comment by @MikeC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732623/javascript-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code#comment62939986_37732623